# Date format for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

I’m loading data into a MySQL table with PHP using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.  There are date fields in the import file that are in the format 10/11/2021 02:49 PM America/New York.  How do I deal with the time zone text at the end?  I have tried stripping it off, but can’t get it to work.  The date comes in as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 every time.

Variations I have tried….

```
SET revision_date = STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(@revision_date, 19), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %A'),
SET revision_date = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(@revision_date, 0, 19), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %A'),
SET revision_date = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(@revision_date, 0, -17), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %A'),
```

The only thing I've been able to get to work is stripping the time zone off in the csv file before importing and using…

```
SET revision_date = STR_TO_DATE(@revision_date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %A'),
```

New data will be loaded frequently, and there are several thousand line of data in the CSV file, times three date fields, so I really would like to deal with it on the import if possible.

Comment: write a program to read and convert the date section as desired before you can save the details in the database. simple

Comment: How about just store the date value in table as `VARCHAR()` first? Then afterward, create a new column with `DATETIME` format, use a query to convert the date and populate the new column with it. It might be faster than trying to figure out what is the correct syntax to convert from `LOAD DATA...`

Comment: Good to know @Kevbo. You can post an answer and share with us the solution you've come up with. Include the steps of creating new column (if any), importing it then your query of converting to the correct date format. Then you can accept it as your answer for this question so it'll help others who might encounter the same issue in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question with my solution for future reference.  Date data was loaded into table as is, into a VARCHAR() field.  Then re-formatted into a date format by stripping off the time zone text, when the table was queried for that field.

```
$revision_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(substr($revision_date, 0, 19)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample date you have given is using a 12-hour clock with AM/PM. For that specific date you can use

```
SET revision_date = str_to_date('10/11/2021 02:49 PM America/New York','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p');
```

which returns `2021-10-11 14:49:00`

Note `%p`, not `%A` for the AM/PM indicator.

I'm assuming all dates are in the same format (no mixed 12-hour and 24-hour clock or US/European date formats), and that you're familiar with LOAD DATA INFILE syntax.